# qtip2 balloons and php tables: different balloon content for each row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, qtip2

I'm trying to use the qtip2 jquery plugin to make little tooptips/balloons with content inside them. Here's their .js and .css files:

http://qtip2.com/download

I want it to work with tables that are populated by php from mysql. I'm doing the table like this:

```
 <tbody>
    <?php while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <tr>
            <td title="lname" width="100px">
                <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                    <?php echo(htmlentities($row['last_name'])); ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td title="fname" width="100px">
                <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                    <?php echo(htmlentities($row['first_name'])); ?>
                </div>
            </td>    
            <td width="100px">
                <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                    <?php echo(htmlentities($row['u_name'])); ?>
                </div>
            </td>  
            <td width="100px">
                <div style="width:150px; overflow:hidden;">
                    <?php echo(htmlentities($row['skype_id'])); ?>
                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

all the ugly divs are there to make it look more aligned. anyway...here's the script for the tooltip:

```
        <script>$('td[title]').qtip({
                    show:'click',
                    hide:'unfocus',
                    content: {
                        text: "<?php echo(htmlentities($row['last_name'])); ?>"
                    }

                }); 
        </script>
```

The problem is...I can only get it to display the same friggin content for every cell with 'title'. I want the balloon to display content specific to each $row. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://qtip2.com/options#content.text):

> You can also specify an function that returns the content, which will
>   be run on each consecutive show event. This function can return both
>   static textual content (text or HTML), or a Deferred object (see
>   below) The function is executed with it's scope as the target element,
>   along with both an event and api argument(s) respectively.

So you can do this:

```
content: {
    text: function() {return $(this).closest("tr").find("[title=lname]").text();}
}
```

The idea is, starting from the target element scope (`this`) which we know is a `td[title]`, to somehow produce the text for the tooltip. Since the only instance of that text in your markup is inside the `td[title=lname]`, the code finds that and returns its text.

Comment: ah ha. okay...so what if the content i want in the balloon is from mysql but is stuff i don't want to show up in the table? do i have to retrieve the content to the table and "display:none" for that column? or is there a better way?

Comment: @user2747609: Put it inside a data attribute, e.g. `<td data-whatever="blah blah">`. This is valid HTML, it won't ever be visible and you can still fetch it with `$(...).attr("data-whatever")`. Alternatively you could inject the data directly into JavaScript with `var foo = <?php echo json_encode($php_data); ?>` and refer to that, but IMHO unless the situation is complicated that's just more work for no benefit.

Comment: Do you know why this simple example is not quite working? http://jsfiddle.net/rNKbZ/

Comment: @user2747609: Because qTip renames the `title` attribute to `oldtitle` so the selector cannot find the correct element. Nice... not. Changing `[title=lname]` to `[oldtitle=lname]` takes care of it, but of course that's not a nice solution. Put the text in an attribute of your own as I suggested above.